# Getters and Setters for HashMaps

Tags: java, getter, getter-setter

I understand how to do getters/setters, but I was wondering how to do them with hashmaps?

I tried to put a user in a HashMap, then in another class, to make an if-statement for the user in the HashMap.

Thanks.

Comment: Where's your code? What exactly isn't working / don't you understand?

Comment: This is the first class http://pastebin.com/XzmG3veg

Comment: This is the second class? http://pastebin.com/Wn6L25dE

Comment: @AmitAliOmidi What line(s) are you having trouble with? You might want to consider whipping up a quick [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to demonstrate your exact problem.

Comment: Im just trying to make the hashmap work on the second class

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb, but I'm not even sure which variable is your hashmap. Could you edit your post, add the relevant code there, and explain exactly what your problem is? Error messages, behaviour, etc. "It doesn't work" is as hard to diagnose as telling you doctor just "I feel sick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get objects in and out:

```
map.put(key, value);
value = map.get(key);
```

Pardon me if i'm not interperating your questin correctly.